# Applying different styling on different events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input type="text" class="home" value="google.com" onblur="if(this.value=='')
{this.value='google.com'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='google.com'){this.value=''}" />
```

This is my `input`. It has two event `onblur` and `onfocus`. I want to apply different styling  rules for different events. For example: `style="color:black;"` for `onfocus` and `style="color:red;"` for `onblur`.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a pure CSS solution - it's much simpler and much cleaner!

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="home" value="google.com" />
```

**CSS**

```
.home:focus {
    color:red;
}
```

Once the control loses focus, it will return to it's original state automatically. Or, automagically as I like to say.

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/qwrA7/).

**Additional Information**

See [The dynamic pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 1):

You won't even need to use Javascript for this one. CSS has a focus pseudo-class that you can use for your input field.

```
input.home { color: black }
input.home:focus { color: red }
```

The "onblur" state just becomes the default input class selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="home" value="google.com" 
       onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='google.com'; this.style.color = 'red'}"
       onfocus="if(this.value=='google.com'){this.value=''; this.style.color = 'black'}" />
```

However, I would recommend James Hill's solution.